# xmlns declaration broke my xPath filter

Tags: xml, matlab, xpath

I have realized a really stupid xPath filter in MatLab:

```
% Construct the DOM.
docNode = xmlread('C:\Users\MATLAB\test.gpx');

% get the xpath mechanism into the workspace
import javax.xml.xpath.*
factory = XPathFactory.newInstance;
xpath = factory.newXPath;

% compile and evaluate the XPath Expression
expression = xpath.compile('gpx/AddressBook/Entry/PhoneNumber');
phoneNumberNode = expression.evaluate(docNode, XPathConstants.NODE);
phoneNumber = phoneNumberNode.getTextContent
```

With this XML (specifically a .gpx file) it works:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1' standalone='yes' ?>
<gpx version='1.1' creator='TTTracklog V.1.13'>
    <AddressBook>
       <Entry>
          <Name>Friendly J. Mathworker</Name>
          <PhoneNumber>(508) 647-7000</PhoneNumber>
          <Address hasZip="no" type="work">3 Apple Hill Dr, Natick MA</Address>
       </Entry>
    </AddressBook>
</gpx>
```

and text (508) 647-7000 is returned.
Simply adding xmlns attribute to gpx node in this way:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1' standalone='yes' ?>
<gpx version='1.1' creator='TTTracklog V.1.13'  xmlns='http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1'>
    <AddressBook>
       <Entry>
          <Name>Friendly J. Mathworker</Name>
          <PhoneNumber>(508) 647-7000</PhoneNumber>
          <Address hasZip="no" type="work">3 Apple Hill Dr, Natick MA</Address>
       </Entry>
    </AddressBook>
</gpx>
```

gave me error, and matlab report:

> ??? Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.
>
> Error in ==> test at 12 phoneNumber = phoneNumberNode.getTextContent

Why? How can I avoid that error?

Comment: I don't know MatLab, but from an XML point of view, you have now placed your gpx (etc.) element in the http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 namespace, and XPath is looking for it in the global namespace. You need to somehow make the namespace known to MatLab and then qualify the gpx element in the XPath expression.

Comment: Good question, +1. In case you don't have mechanisms in Matlab to register a namespace, you can alwys use an expression like this: `*[name()= 'gpx']
    /*[name()='AddressBook']
       /*[name()='Entry']
          /*[name() = 'PhoneNumber']`

Comment: @_Mariano: Was my answer useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dabbler's comment above is correct. Since you have added a default namespace to your XML document, you must also alter your XPath expression to search for nodes in your new default namespace.

Unqualified names in XPath expressions (like `AddressBook`) are in the `null` XML namespace, not the default XML namespace of your document.

So you want to somehow register your new namespace with your `xpath` object. Like:

```
{"foo": "http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1"}
```

and then alter your XPath expression to:

```
foo:gpx/foo:AddressBook/foo:Entry/foo:PhoneNumber
```

There are docs on how to do this with the `javax.xml.xpath` API here:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi/index.html#N1022D

However, I'm not sure how this translates to Matlab, exactly.

Comment: You're right! I should declarate a path name. I've posted the question on matlab forum. I will report it as soon they will answer me.

Comment: Should translate exactly, because it's using the Java classes.

Comment: For a MATLAB-specific implementation, I posted an example in this blog comment: http://blogs.mathworks.com/desktop/2010/11/01/xml-and-matlab-navigating-a-tree/#comment-8353 You still need to use a java class for the NamespaceContext

Answer (score 6):

**In case you cannot register the default namespace with an associated prefix, use:**

```
*[name()= 'gpx']
    /*[name()='AddressBook']
       /*[name()='Entry']
          /*[name() = 'PhoneNumber']
```

**instead of:**

```
gpx/AddressBook/Entry/PhoneNumber
```

**Here is a complete, XSLT-based, verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select=
     "*[name()= 'gpx']
    /*[name()='AddressBook']
       /*[name()='Entry']
          /*[name() = 'PhoneNumber']
   "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1' standalone='yes' ?>
<gpx version='1.1' creator='TTTracklog V.1.13'  xmlns='http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1'>
    <AddressBook>
       <Entry>
          <Name>Friendly J. Mathworker</Name>
          <PhoneNumber>(508) 647-7000</PhoneNumber>
          <Address hasZip="no" type="work">3 Apple Hill Dr, Natick MA</Address>
       </Entry>
    </AddressBook>
</gpx>
```

**the wanted element is selected and copied to the output**:

```
<PhoneNumber xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1">(508) 647-7000</PhoneNumber>
```

Comment: The code:
`e1 = xPath.compile('*[name()= "gpx"]/*[name()= "trk"]');
    s = e1.evaluate(gpx, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    sNumber = s.getLength;`
compile and return me exact value. While
`e2 = xPath.compile('*[name()= "gpx"]/*[name()= "trk[1]"]/*[name()= "trkseg"]');
    s = e2.evaluate(gpx, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    sNumber = s.getLength;`
always return 0 value. Why? Is this for '[1]' of the second expression?

Comment: @Mariano: Of course. Names can only contain alphanumeric characters (starting with alpha) -- not `[]`. You actually want: `*[name()='trk'][1]`

Comment: You are the man! Last thing: what about attribute? For example: how can I get latitude and longitude with this notation?
I have something like `gpx/trk[1]/trkseg[1]/trkpt[2]/@lat` that i need to rewrite using name().

Comment: @Mariano: There are no `lat` attributes (and also no attributes with names that could be for longitude, in your provided XML document. So this is just my *guess* having not seen the XML document alluded for -- use: `*[name()='gpx']/*[name()='trk'][1]/*[name()='trkseg'][1]/*[name()='trkpt'][2]/@lat`

Comment: Look this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_eXchange_Format
Attributes "lat" and "lon" are written inside `trkpt` tag.

Anyway you was right! ;)

Comment: How I can select subling with name()?

Comment: @Cherry, `following-sibling::*[name() = 'xxx']`